# Vaprobash: Create new VM failed

Tags: laravel, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm trying to install a new VM with VAPROBASH (https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash)
but the installation fails when mounting NFS shared folders

I'm using Mac OsX 10.9.2, Vagrant 1.6.2, VirtualBox 4.2.20

```
=> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o 'nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime' 192.168.22.1:'/Users/user/Sites/myfolder' /vagrant

Stdout from the command:

Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
mount.nfs: requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks! I need to start a project!

Comment: Not a direct answer - but have you tried Homestead? http://laravel.com/docs/homestead

Comment: No, I don´t know that this exists!!! thanks!

Comment: It only got released in the past couple of days

Comment: oh no! I need apache, Homestead works only with nginx :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´ve found the solution:

> adding the line 127.0.0.1 localhost to the /etc/hosts file worked for me as well
>
> I'm with vagrant 1.6.2 and vbox 4.3.10
>
> https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1941#issuecomment-43098597